# Adjust height of xib containing UIStackView when elements are hidden

Tags: ios, swift, xib, uistackview

[image]

I have an xib containing a stackview with child stack views (following Ray Wenderlichs tutorial). I wish to hide one of the child stackviews so that the height of the xib adjusts to the visible child stackviews. However currently it remains at the original fixed height and the visible stackviews are spread across it.

[image]

Here are the settings for the top level stack view:
[image]

Can anyone advise on how to make the xib height adjust to fit the visible content size?

Edit 1:
After removing the heights of each of the child stack views and make the bottom constraint of the top level stack view >= 8 to the superview, the problem still happens but the layout has changed:

[image]

Edit 2:
After add a trailing constraint, the child stackviews no longer stretch across the xib, but the height of the xib does not compress:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

The issue is because you've fixed the `bottom` `constraint` of the `StackView` to the `HeaderView's` `bottom` as `8`.

Now, the `StackView` won't be able to reduce its `height` according to its content.

**Solution:**

Make it as `>= 8`, i.e.

```
bottom >= StackView.bottom + 8
```

That way `StackView` will adjust its height as per its contents.

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Problem still persists after doing this.

Comment: Remove the height constraints of all the stack views.

Comment: Sorry, issue is still there.

Comment: Are you referring to the orange part as the extra part of the stackView?

Comment: No, the orange part is the collection view for Evidence. In the above image, I have hidden the Requirement Score Details Stack View.

Comment: Please add the screenshot where you're getting the issue.

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the required constraints. See if that works for you.

Comment: Question updated. For some reason I cannot add a trailing constraint to the top level stack view.

Comment: And why is that? Why not adding trailing constraint? Without that the stackView won't be able to calculate its proper size.

Comment: OK, I had translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set instead of automatic for the top level stack view. The child stackviews are no longer being spread out, but the height of the xib does not adjust. Will update the question with the new layout.

Comment: The height of the xib won't reduce in Xcode. But the constraints will be reflected with proper height when you run the project.